# Add POCO / Entity to DbContext for Custom Query / Procedure Without Creating a Table in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

### Background

I am using EF Core 3 for an application with a number of POCOs in a DbContext that I ***want*** to be created as database tables - no problem here!  I use Linq queries to get data here, and life is good.

I also have some raw SQL queries and procedures for some more complex reporting.  I've created POCOs for the returned data, and added to the DbContext as a DbSet:

```
public class FooBarContext : DbContext
{
    // ...

    public DbSet<FooReport> FooReport { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Where `FooReport` looks like:

```
public class FooReport
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

### The Problem / Workaround

This creates a migration for **creating a new table** called `FooReport`, which isn't what I want.

My workaround right now is to manually remove this action from the `Migration` that is generated, so that, in essence, I have an empty migration:

```
public partial class AddFooReport : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        // intentionally clear this out, so the entity isn't created / dropped as a table

        // migrationBuilder.CreateTable("FooReport", ... );
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        // intentionally clear this out, so the entity isn't created / dropped as a table

        // migrationBuilder.DropTable("FooReport");
    }
}
```

Then I'm able to call the procedure like so:

```
var result = this._fooBarContext.Set<FooReport>(@"[SP_FooReport]")
    .FromSqlRaw(sql)
    .ToList();
```

**This does work**, but seems hacky.

I also (unsuccessfully) tried to solve this problem by adding the `NotMapped` decorator to the `FooReport` POCO, but then the query itself fails.

### TL;DR; - Can you define a `DbSet` as an entity that is specifically NOT a table?

Answer (score 1):

In EF Core 3+ simply remove the Key from FooReport to make it a [Keyless Entity Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    
 modelBuilder.Entity<FooReport>().HasNoKey();
 //. . .

}
```

In EF 5 there's an attribute for this too:

```
[Keyless]
public class FooReport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: From the docs linked that looks like exactly what I want, however the IDE says it's not defined - am I missing a package reference perhaps?  I would have expected it to be in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`

Comment: Ah, I see now it's only available in EF Core 5+, which is in preview now :-/ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396213/entity-framework-keyless-data-annotation-missing)

Comment: See update.  The feature is in EF Core 3, just not the attribute.  EF Core 3 there you have to use Fluent Configuration in OnModelCreating.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `modelBuilder.Ignore<FooReport>();` call to `OnModelCreating` method on your DbContext or mark `FooReport` with `NotMapped` attribute.